# How to find the item index number in a query result

Tags: sql, sql-server

is there a simple way to get the number of the current item in a simple SELECT? I need to deliver a column based on a calculation that involves the number of the current index in the select. I am simplifing my problem to an extreme, but roughly speaking, here is an example:

```
SELECT column1 * ITEMINDEX FROM table
```

I hope I am being clear. I am using SQL Server. Thank you.

Comment: Can you add an autonumber field to the table?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In `SQL Server 2005+`:

```
SELECT  m.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY column) AS rn
FROM    mytable m
```

`SQL` does not have concept of implicit row number, that's why you need `ORDER BY` clause to define the order of rows.